# Rails Can't get :recource routing working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this `resources :companies` in my routes.rb.

And I have a companies_controller.rb in app/controllers.

Why am I getting this error when I try and load /companies or /companies/new?

```
Missing template companies/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/Pabi/code/pandora/app/views"
  * "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-extras-0.0.6/app/views"
  * "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-5a2b7b5bc683/app/views"
  * "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/app/views"
  * "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/devise-e538f02f30be/app/views"
Application Frames All Frame
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have `new.html.erb` in `app/views/companies`?

Comment: Figured it out. The problem was that I had named the folder company and not companies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `resources :companies` does it create the routes for you, not the files that those routes require. The easiest way to generate those files is to run the command `rails g scaffold company`. This command creates the necessary model, view, and controller a company needs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you have to create or make sure `/app/views/companies/new.html.erb`  when you load

http://localhost:300/companies/new